# How do I do multiple transforms in one tag with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, transform, css-transforms

I am making a bunch of basic charts in HTML and SVG. To make x and y values easier to work with, I am doing a horizontal mirror like this:

```
<g class="mirror" transform="translate(0,200) scale(1,-1)">
```

This works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/as6naLsb/

However, I want to try and do this in CSS. When I take the transform out of the  tag and try and put it in CSS like this:

```
g.mirror{
        transform:translate(0,200) scale(1,-1);
    }
```

it does not work.

When I inspect in the console of Chrome, it says "invalid property."

What is the correct way of doing it so I don't have to put the transform attribute in each  tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `px` unit after the `0` and `200` in your translate transform. Try this:

```
transform: translate(0px, 200px) scale(1, -1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/as6naLsb/1/

I’m not sure why it worked as an inline style but you need the units :)

Comment: When inline, it's a svg property, the rules are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

removing: `transform="translate(0,200) scale(1,-1)"`

and adding:

```
.chart {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Gives the same output.